# How can Siu prove the lower semi-continuity of plurigenera by extension theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

([crossposted from m.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244970/how-can-siu-prove-the-lower-semi-continuity-of-plurigenera-by-extension-theorem))

I am a novice in the field of complex geometry.  The following question seems to  be so  simple  that no one have explained  it in related papers.

In the famous paper---*Siu, Yum-Tong Invariance of plurigenera. Invent. Math. 134 (1998)* , the main theorem is as follows.

> Let $\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta$ be a smooth projective family of compact complex manifolds parametrized by the open unit 1 -disk $\Delta$. Assume that the fibers $X_{t}=\pi^{-1}(t), t \in \Delta$, are of general type. Then for every positive integer $m$ the plurigenus $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbf{C}} \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ is independent of $t \in \Delta$, where $K_{X_{t}}$ is the canonical line bundle of $X_{t}$.

Siu reduced this problem to an extension problem.  He wrote:

> The Main Theorem is therefore equivalent to the statement that for every $t \in \Delta$ and every positive integer $m$ every element of $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ can be extended to an element of $\Gamma\left(X, m K_{X}\right)$.

Accoding to my understanding, by the **Gruert upper-semicontinuity theorem**, that for every $t \in \Delta$ and every positive integer $m$ every element of $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ can be extended to an element of $\Gamma\left(X, m K_{X}\right)$  is equivalent to the lower semi-continuity of  $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ near $t=0$.

However I am unable to write it down step by step.

According to the definition of the  **lower semi-continuity**  and  $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)\in \mathbb{Z}$, we need to  find a small positive number $\varepsilon$ such that  $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right) \leq  \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ for any $t<\varepsilon$.

So for a fixed small $t$, we want to establish an injective map $$\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right) \to  \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right).$$

Via the extension theorem, a natural map seens to be the following.
$$v: s\mapsto S\mapsto S|_{X_t},$$
where $s\in \Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$, S its extension obtained by the extension theorem.

However, I cannot prove the injectivity of the above map $v$. In fact, for any different sections $s_1$  and $s_2$, we can find some $\varepsilon$ (depends on $s_1$  and $s_2$) such that $v(s_1)\neq v(s_2)$ for $t\leq \varepsilon$. But the difficulty is that the choice of $\varepsilon$  depends on $s_1$  and $s_2$.

So we cannot compare the dimension of $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$  with $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ for a fixed $t$.

My question: How to prove the injectivity of the above map $v$. That is to say,  how to compare the dimension of $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$  with $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ for a fixed $t$.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using this boldface?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  ?

Comment: @LelongWang You've made about a third of the text of your question boldfaced. Boldface is generally used as a form of emphasis, which should be relatively rare in order to deliberately stand out from the rest of the text; when such a large portion is emphasized in this way, it makes the question difficult to read and focus appropriately.

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to be easier to read; if you think I've over-edited the bolding, feel free to revert or to re-edit for emphasis.

Comment: The map $v$ is a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces. Thus it suffices to check that it maps a given basis of $H^0(X_0,mK_{X_0})$ to a linearly independent set, for $|t|$ sufficiently small. These are finitely many conditions to check, which are open in the usual topology of the parameter $t$, and which hold at $t=0$, and so you are done.

Comment: @YangMills Thank you. If you examine it carefully, you may find it seems  impossible to judge whether a collection of  elements  is a   linearly independent set of  elements in $H^0(X_t,mK_{X_t})$ or not for any fixed $t$.  Here we may take the direct limit information into account, see the answer in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244970/how-can-siu-prove-the-lower-semi-continuity-of-plurigenera-by-extension-theorem

Comment: I disagree with your comment. For clarity let $v_t$ be the linear map you defined above. Fix a basis $\{s_j\}$ of $H^0(X_0,mK_{X_0})$. Suppose what you want fails, then you can find $t_i\to 0$ and a nontrivial linear dependence relation between the $v_{t_i}(s_j)$, namely $\sum_j \lambda_j(t_i) v_{t_i}(s_j)=0$. By scaling you may assume that $\sum_j |\lambda_j(t_i)|^2=1$. Then up to subsequence you can take a nontrivial limit of these coefficients, and since the limit of $v_{t_i}(s_j)$ is $s_j$, passing to the limit gives a linear dependence relation among the $s_j$, contradiction.

Comment: @YangMills Thank u very much for your nice proof. One thing confused me very much is the  notion of "convergence"  in your argument.  The "constant" sequence $\{\sum_{j} \lambda_{j}\left(t_{i}\right) v_{t i}\left(s_{j}\right)=0\}$ tends to 0 (vector in $H^{0}\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$) and  the limit of  v_{t_ i}\left(s_{j}\right)  is $s_{j}$. Then which topology is used when talking about the "convergence" ? This seems to be  the kind of problem you have to be very careful about when you talk about convergence, since $X_t\to X_0$ formally while many objects in them are quite different .

Comment: It is not hard, just choose a $C^\infty$ trivialization of your family, so you can view $X_t$ as the same smooth manifold as $X_0$ with a smoothly varying family of complex structures, and the sections $v_{t_i}(s_j)$ can all be viewed as smooth sections of a fixed smooth vector bundle over the smooth manifold $X_0$ (the $m$th self tensor product of the bundle of smooth complex-valued $n$-forms), and in this sense they converge in the smooth topology to $s_j$ as $t_i\to 0$.

Comment: I should add that, as you suspected, this kind of arguments are standard in the area, which is why Siu did not elaborate on this point

Comment: @YangMills Thanks a lot. In  2004 Invariance of Plurigenera and Torsion-Freeness
of Direct Image Sheaves of Pluricanonial Bundles
by Yum-Tong Siu, Siu studied the "Extension from singular fiber ".
So is it still right for a nonsmooth family that the  extension theorem 
can  imply the lower semi-continuity of the dimension of the space of global 
sections of $mK_{X_t}$ (assume $X_0$ is the unique singular fiber)?

Comment: After all, for a nonsmooth family, there is no $C^{\infty}$ trivialization of the family any more.